# Android rawQuery help

Tags: android, sqlite

I was wondering how I could query my database of 1400 items and get only the `DISTINCT` types and row ids. Below is the actual sql that I want to run by my program crashes if I dont return ids.

```
 return mDb.rawQuery("SELECT DISTINCT Type from the_foods",null);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I figured it out. I had to use the group by ("Type"): return mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_TYPE,KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME},null,
                    null, "Type", null, null, null);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to use the group by ("Type"):

```
return mDb.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_TYPE,KEY_ROWID,KEY_NAME},null, null, "Type", null, null, null);
```